# How far can an implied pronoun be?

Tags: pronouns

The following sentence my friend came up with seems wrong to me:

(1) "The vulnerability is due to insufficient sanitization of user-supplied data before being used to execute commands."

Compare that with something from nytimes.com, which sounds ok:

(2) "Today, tourists go through an elaborate screening process before being allowed to visit."

In (1), "before being" connotes "A of X before X is Y", where A = insufficient sanitization, X = user-supplied data, and Y = used to execute commands

In (2), "before being" connotes "A of X before X are Y", where A = elaborate screening, X = tourists, and Y = allowed to visit.

What exactly is wrong with the grammar of (1)?

Comment: I just noticed that the object "tourists" in (2) appears at the beginning unlike in (1). I think in (1), "vulnerability", and not "user-supplied data", becomes the object of the implied pronoun. Modified question: can someone explain it clearly?

Comment: The subject of _being used_ is sposta be _data_, but the prepositional phrase doesn't modify _data_. It modifies _sanitization_, and therefore the normal rules would predict that it's the **sanitization** that's _being used to execute commands_. Simple fix is to put the subject back in: _before it is used to execute commands_. There's no reason to use a participle when a simple clause will do better.

Comment: @JohnLawler Wouldn't it be the implied *subject* of *sanitization*, or the subject of the whole main clause, i.e.  *vulnerability* which would be regarded as the subject of *being used to execute commands*? Praps? (otherwise my answer below is wrong ... although I decided against mention 'subjects' of nouns ...)

Comment: Dunno. Ask the OP. But (1) clearly implies to me that dirty data are being used to formulate commands, possibly by determining which subprogram gets executed in each case. This is a serious problem in programming if the programmer can't depend on the information being sanitized (in any of hundreds of arbitrary ways) before becoming grist for the output mill.

Comment: @Araucaria In my first comment, by "object" I meant "subject" (can't seem to edit the comment now). John Lawler's interpretation of (1) is correct; his simple suggestion of using "it" sounds good. Your explanation is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Today, tourists go through an elaborate screening process before being allowed to visit.

The subordinate clause here is inside a Prepositional Phrase (some people would analyse it as being a clause with a subordinating conjunction):

- before being allowed to visit.

Here we have to use an *-ing* form of the verb because there is no subject. It's the passive auxiliary *BE* here which is taking the  *-ing* form. If we omit the subject we cannot use a tensed verb. If we include it we can:

- before they are allowed to visit.

However, we can only drop the subject in a subordinate clause like this if it is the same as the subject in the main clause. If it is a different subject we can't. It we put the missing words back in to the example above, we get the following:

> Today, **tourists**(i) go through an elaborate screening process before
>      **their**(i) being allowed to visit.

Here it's clear that *tourists* and *their* are the same people. However in the other sentence in the Original Poster's first example there is a problem:

> The vulnerability(i) is due to insufficient sanitization of user-supplied data(ii) before ___(ii) being used to execute commands.

Here the subject of the main clause is *the vulnerability*.  However, the writer's intended subject of the subordinate clause is not *the vulnerability* but *the user supplied data*. The problem is *user supplied data* cannot grammatically be the subject here, because it isn't the subject of the main clause! Because the subjects of the two clauses are different, we cannot drop the subject in the subordinate one. The correct sentence would have to read thus:

> The vulnerability is due to insufficient sanitization of user-supplied data before its being used to execute commands.

The *its* here is a bit ambiguous so we may prefer a tensed clause with a full subject:

> The vulnerability is due to insufficient sanitization of user-supplied data before this data is used to execute commands.

Answer (score 0):

Your structural analysis is a little off.  The NYT sentence has the form *A go through B **before** C,* where B and C are a sequence of events that both happen to A.  In your friend's sentence, the intended meaning is *A is caused by B happening to D **before** C happens to D*.  So in the second sentence we are expecting two things that relate to A, but instead are presented with two things that relate to D, which is not conveyed correctly by the structure.